# SQL performance: Which is quicker? IN() versus JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, database-performance

This is a question to which I've never gotten a definitive answer. I am using MySQL in this example.

Given a reasonably large set of values (lets say 500). Is it quicker to search a table using these values with an IN() clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN(values)
```

Or by creating a temporary table in memory, populating it with the values and joining it to the table being searched:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp_table` (`field` varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES (values)

SELECT * FROM table t1 JOIN temp_table t2 ON t1.field = t2.field
```

Both methods will produce same result set.

I have done some of my own basic benchmarking tests and found that when dealing with more than 500 values it becomes quicker to use a temporary table than an IN() clause.

Can someone explain to me the inner workings of MySQL and what a proper answer to this question is?

Thanks,
Leo

Comment: Please post your benchmarks in order for them to be verified. Do you have index on field?

Comment: You do realize that the answer hugely depends on the structure of your database? Creating temp table, populating it and joining a table involves lots of CPU work opposed to using a query with IN operator. The IO will be quicker due to memory storage, however InnoDB can hold its working dataset in memory too. If you do an `IN` search based on primary key of InnoDB table - it will beat the temp table hands down.

Comment: Would be interesting if you posted the explain plan for both too.

Comment: Both fields are indexed but not primary. My benchmarks gave rough results indicating that 500 values was the turning point. I'm interested to know what is happening 'behind the scenes' when using an IN() clause.

Comment: These are all MyISAM tables I should add

Answer (score 2):

From MySql online documentation, [IN()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) :

> IN (value,...)
>
> If all values are **constants**, they are evaluated according to the type of expr and sorted.
>   The search for the item then is done using a binary search. This means
>   IN is very quick if the IN value list consists entirely of constants.
>   Otherwise, type conversion takes place according to the rules
>   described in Section 11.2, “Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation”,
>   but applied to all the arguments.

Considering that I believe it makes sense to use IN() with a set of constants, otherwise you should use subquery on another table.

You can consider usign [EXISTS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) instead of JOIN when items are retrieved from an other table, it would significantly faster for large data set

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t1 
WHERE EXISTS 
      (
        SELECT * 
        FROM temp_table t2 
        WHERE t1.field = t2.field
      )
```

Comment: I don't understand the binary search bit. For that to work the column would need to be sorted and thus presumably indexed? So why not just look it up from the index? (Unless they mean the search uses binary collation semantics rather than talking about an actual [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Comment: @Martin Smith : Binary search (per doc used only for constants) makes sense when a set of constants is sorted, so this mean that server does sort and only then perform binary search

Comment: Ah I see. I was thinking the other way around. So MySQL does a full table scan then does a binary search in the constant list for each value? What about if the column is indexed and the in clause only has a couple of values. A couple of index seeks would surely be more efficient?

Comment: @Martin Smith : I'm not an expert in this so I could be wrong, but as far as I understand Index Seek is automatically applies by optimizer when a query returns solid portion of data from a table, but how it ensures that Index Seek would be preffered whilst doing search for values int he IN(...) list? Hope I've expressed thoughts clear

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer depends on many things.

You've done the work already - if your benchmarking tells you that using a temporary table is faster, then that's the way to go.

Remember to benchmark again if you change the hardware, or dramatically alter the schema.